# read JSON line by line with QT

Tags: c++, json, qt, qt5

I have a JSON like this:

```
{
    "09:32 24.09.2018": "456",
    "09:56 24.09.2018": "854",
    "09:57 24.09.2018": "854",
    "09:59 24.09.2018": "853",
    "10:00 24.09.2018": "369",
    "10:01 24.09.2018": "369"
}
```

How can I read this line by line in QT5. I would like to write it in a `QTableWidget` to have "09:32 24.09.2018" in first row / first column, "456" in first row / second column, "09:56 24.09.2018" second row / first column and so on..

My current loading works like this:

```
QJsonDocument getFile = loadJson("test");
QJsonObject obj = getFile.object();
```

with:

```
QJsonDocument MainWindow::loadJson(QString fileName) {
    QFile jsonFile(fileName);
    jsonFile.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
    return QJsonDocument().fromJson(jsonFile.readAll());
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Did you look into Qt doc.? [`QJsonObject`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsonobject.html). It can be accessed like a std container. I would expect that you can iterate through values. Note, these are stored as `key_type`/`mapped_type` where `key_type` is a `QString`. Sounds quite promising to me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can iterate over the QJsonObject to transverse it:

```
QString val;
QFile file;
//set the file name
file.setFileName("foo.json");
//open the file name
file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text);
//read the file name
val = file.readAll();
//close the file name
file.close();

//string to json doc
QJsonDocument doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(val.toUtf8());
//json doc to json object
QJsonObject object = doc.object();
//json object can be iterated
for (auto it = object.begin(), end=object.end(); it != end; ++it)
{
    qDebug() << "Key: " << it.key() << "Val: " << it.value();
}
```

Comment: QJsonObject provides an iterator to traverse it, you don't even need the  QVarianMap.

Comment: thanks a lot! @sandwood